# IPython notebook kernel keeps failing. How can I work with large array computations?

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook, large-data, bigdata

I'm doing some heavy lifting with my IPython notebooks, where I am working element-by-element operations on arrays shaped (50, 10000, 10000), several times.

This is already after I have significantly broken up the data into "workable" pieces.

Sadly, the kernel to my IPython notebook still dies.

(1) Why exactly is the kernel dying? Is it that storage is being maxed?

(2) What are my options? Should I save the outputs and import them into new notebooks?

EDIT: The code I'm using is something like this. The matrix is an external input.

The bottleneck is here:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

matrix # already defined, an input
          # matrix.shape is (12534, 12534)

from scipy.special import eval_legendre  ##special scipy function
arr = np.arange(513) 

bottleneck = eval_legendre(arr[:, None, None], dotproductmatrix)
```

Obviously, that won't work. So, I'm try to do the legendre evaluation in parts